# Second Page for Legend in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, legend, arcgis-10.3

I'm looking for a way to have a second page in the layout view in ArcGIS 10.3. The map I'm making fills the whole page and I'd like to make the legend go onto a second page. Other solutions are welcome if it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

ArcMap basically does one page per mxd unless you use data driven pages (DDP). So the easiest thing to do is create a second mxd as a copy of the first, and just move the dataframe the legend is based on off the page and create a new layout with just the legend and whatever other elements you want. You do have to watch making changes to one file and not the other. You could save symbology out as a layer (.lyr) file and apply that to your copy, or create a new copy of the mxd each time to update any symbology changes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up doing this and it worked just fine.

Comment: @JamesMoore Happy to help. Please consider [clicking the check mark to accept the answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).